# SQL SERVER query, Mutual Rows in Given ID

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a sql server query question. I have a table like below. Giving a parameter to stored procedure, I need to query mutual CustomFields in lists that I want. For example, if ListID is given 1 and 2 and 3, result table will have columns that gives me 'FullName' in that case, because only 'FullName' is in all three ID's. I did that which solved the issue somehow, but looking for a better and precise practice. Thanks

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CustomField) 
FROM CustomFields a
WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT count(*) 
      FROM CustomFields b 
      WHERE a.CustomField = b.CustomField 
      HAVING count(*)>2
)
ORDER BY a.CustomField


CustomField   ListID
PhoneNumber   1
Unvan         1
FullName      2
Surname       2
Regiob        2
FullName      3
BirthPlace    3
FullName      1
```

Comment: Unless you're always looking for the field name that shares **at least three** identifiers, this sounds like you'd need to use a table value parameter. What version of SQL Server are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a more common approach to find CustomFields that are in groups 1, 2 and 3:

```
SELECT  CustomField
FROM    CustomFields
WHERE   ListID in (1,2,3)
GROUP BY
        CustomField
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT ListId) = 3
```

No subquery required, and the `where` clause filters out uninteresting groups before the `group by`.

Comment: This is good for the example posted in the question, but what if the IDs change? And what if you want to have the `CustomField` where the `ListID` matches 7, 20, 47, and 56 - for example?

Comment: @Yuck: You'd use `ListID in (7,20,47,56)` and `count(distinct ListId) = 4`.  How you pass the variables depends on your client language and the version of SQL Server that you're using.

Comment: The "IN" clause does not allow the use of parameters, so you cannot have something like `...where ListID in (@SomeList)`. However, it does support subqueries, lke `...where ListId in (select ListId from #Temp)`

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking of something more along these lines, which is adapted from @Andomar and is a little more general.

```
CREATE TYPE ListIdType AS TABLE (
  ListId int PRIMARY KEY
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE S
    @ListIdTable ListIdType READONLY
AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT  CustomField
FROM    CustomFields
WHERE   ListID in (SELECT ListId FROM @ListIdTable)
GROUP BY
        CustomField
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT ListId) = (SELECT COUNT(ListId) FROM @ListIdTable)

END;
```

Comment: That's definitely the way to go if you have SQL Server 2008+ and a client language that supports table variables +1

Comment: I guess, I have to create a temp table in the database, that will stay permanently